# Aluminum to prevent Iron corrosion

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metallurgy

I have heard of how zinc is used to prevent corrosion of iron. So why not use aluminium coat instead? After all Aluminum oxide forms a stable coat over the surface.

Comment: Both are used, even together (Zincalume).

Comment: Oh I didn't know. Everybody I asked this question to in the past thought I was crazy

Answer (score 2):

Aluminum, just like zinc, is already widely used to coat iron surfaces to prevent corrosion (in the elemental form, or in combination with other metals, like zinc). You can deposit aluminum on practically any surface (including plastics). On metals it is done by electrochemical deposition.

There are several companies working with this type of coating nowadays, including AlumiPlate (http://www.alumiplate.com/).

Comment: Not all aluminum on metals is deposited electrolytically.  Hot dip aluminizing is a thing in steel strip manufacturing.  Also aluminum is pasivating rather than cathodicat ambient temperatures but becomes truly protective at high temperature.

Comment: No one mentioned aluminum anodes; So many tons of anodes are used on an oil platform that the weight must be considered in the design. Some Al is dipped, some is sprayed , some is vapor deposited: some  coatings are diffused into the steel at high temperature.